# Laravel's db:seed is not inserting any record in database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, factory, faker

I am using Laravel 5.6 and database seeder is not working. I am trying to insert 100 new data in my database but nothing is being inserted. No error is being shown and I don't know why `php artisan db:seed` is not working

Here's my `DatabaseSeeder.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $students = factory(App\Student::class, 100)->make();
    }
}
```

Here's my `StudentFactory.php`

```
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Student::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'id' => $faker->unique()->numberBetween(1,1000),
        'rfid_number' => $faker->unique()->numberBetween(1,1000),
        'first_name' => $faker->firstName,
        'middle_name' => $faker->lastName,
        'last_name' => $faker->lastName,
        'name_extension' => $faker->suffix,
        'email' => $faker->safeEmail,
        'password' => '$2y$10$TKh8H1.PfQx37YgCzwiKb.KjNyWgaHb9cbcoQgdIVFlYg7B77UdFm', // secret
        'photo' => '',
        'house_number' => $faker->buildingNumber,
        'barangay' => $faker->streetName,
        'city' => $faker->city,
        'province' => $faker->state,
        'zip_code' => $faker->postCode,
        'birth_date' => $faker->date('Y-m-d'),
        'birth_place' => $faker->streetAddress,
        'gender' => 'Male',
        'religion' => 'Roman Catholic',
        'landline_number' => $faker->tollFreePhoneNumber,
        'mobile_number' => $faker->tollFreePhoneNumber,
        'father_name' => $faker->name,
        'father_occupation' => $faker->jobTitle,
        'mother_name' => $faker->name,
        'mother_occupation' => $faker->jobTitle,
        'guardian_name' => $faker->name,
        'guardian_occupation' => $faker->jobTitle,
        'guardian_address' => $faker->streetAddress,
        'year' => $faker->numberBetween(1,6),
        'section' => $faker->cityPrefix,
        'created_at' => now(),
        'updated_at' => now()
    ];
});
```

and it shows no error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `create()` method:

```
$students = factory(App\Student::class, 100)->create();
```

Comment: OMG :( Thank you brother